# using functions for controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was using controllers like this

```
.controller("somename",function($scope,$http){
//some get function to fetch data
$scope.data = dataReturned;
$scope.$apply();
});
```

It was working fine. Then I wanted to use functions after reading [johnpapa's blog](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and changed it to the one like below

```
.controller("somename",someNameController);
function someNameController(){
var someName = this;
//some get function to fetch data
    this.data = dataReturned;
    this.$apply();
};
```

but this did not work as `this.$apply` is not a function

When I added $scope(which is not recommended) it started working

```
 .controller("somename",someNameController);
    function someNameController($scope){
    var someName = this;
    //some get function to fetch data
        $scope.data = dataReturned;
        $scope.$apply();
    };
```

is it possible to eliminate the passing of  `$scope` in  `function someNameController($scope)` ?

Comment: Err, why is taking `$scope` as an argument not recommended? Because it breaks on minification (for which, you can use the array or `$inject` solutions)? What about other dependency injections?

Comment: Let the blogs singing over there. The angular way of doing this is your first way, ie, explicitly injecting the dependencies (Moreover: .controller("somename", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){ ... }]) ). That code is much more clear.

Comment: @vignesh, are you sure that you need call `$apply`? can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: @Grundy http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/RkykR/1159/
try commenting the $scope.$apply

Also i think its due to the usage of $.get instead of $http.get. Is it not allowed to use $.get?

Comment: you just do it wrong :-) i a [bit fix it](http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/1160/) and `$apply` not needed, and jQuery also not needed

Comment: also, when you use angular in most cases jquery not needed, and with request also

Comment: Thanks :) 
I was facing issue related to x-domain requests when i used $http.get which forced me to use $.get. 
Will try to resolve that

Comment: @vignesh, you just can see about settings for `$http.get` it same as `$.get`

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to skip the $scope? in order to get the reference of all the methods and variables in the controller you have to use the $scope .thanks

Comment: open the style guide, it recommends using 'this' contrary to scope. He wants to follow that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with controllers as functions and inject dependencies without breaking anything during the minification process.

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    var MainCtrl = function($scope){

       // Do something

    };

    MainCtrl.$inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];

    app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

})();
```

Comment: what you want say? :-)

Comment: The easiest way to deal with controllers as functions and the way you can inject dependencies without breaking anything during the minification process.

Comment: you can add this explain to your answer :-)

Comment: I thought was self explanatory because of the context. I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers while blocking code-only questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Answer (score 1):

You're following John Papa's style guide and use the so-called *controller-as* syntax.

The *controller-as* syntax allows using instances of functions in views, and therefore it isn't necessary to inject `$scope` in order to make data available to the view. A simple `this.data = mydata` is enough.

However, when using special functionality available in `$scope`, the `$scope` still has to be injected into the controller function. [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), `$watch()` etc are typically part of that. [This article](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) explains exactly that.

About the controllerAs syntax from John Papa's style guide (emphasis mine):

> Helps avoid the temptation of using `$scope` methods inside a controller
>   when it may otherwise be better to avoid them or move the method to a
>   factory, and reference them from the controller. **Consider using `$scope`
>   in a controller only when needed**. For example when publishing and
>   subscribing events using `$emit`, `$broadcast`, or `$on` consider moving
>   these uses to a factory and invoke from the controller.

The short answer is therefore **no** - there is no way of using `$scope` methods without injecting `$scope` or an other service which has `$scope` as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks @marapet
the $scope is not getting updated if i am not using $scope.$apply after assigning result data to $scope variable, thats why i needed it. Guess i should look for some other way for this instead of using $scope.$apply

Comment: What do you mean by '$scope is note getting updated' - in your view? Do you also use the controller-as syntax in your view (in the controller: `this.data = ...` and in your view: `ng-controller="somename as vw"` and then `{{vw.data}}` ?